# How to resignfirstresponder touching scrollview in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, resignfirstresponder

Creating an iOS app with Xamarin in Visual Studio.

I have a UIViewController that contains a UITextField and a UITableView to display search results. When you type into the textfield the keyboard appears. I also do a search on a backround thread and display the results in the UITableView.

I need to hide the keyboard so that the user can scroll through the search results. How should I do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under below two situations:

1.When you finish searching in background

2.Detect the scroll event of tableView:

```
tableView.Scrolled += (sender, e) => { ViewOnScrolled(sender, e); };
```

you can call:

```
textF.ResignFirstResponder();
```

Or

```
textF.EndEditing(true);
```

Or

```
this.View.EndEditing(true);
```

to hide the keyboard.

Comment: Almost the right answer. I get a runtime error if I add a scroll event to my tableview, because I'm using a TableViewSource that is acting as a delegate. So the way to do it is to override Scrolled in my TableViewSource and call back to the viewcontroller to hide the keyboard.